# New tag and parser in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, html-parsing

I've sketched out a new programming language for client side scripting. I'm familiar with how to build a language, and most of the work that goes into it. I'm prepared for a long project but have a few questions about how to implement it into a HTML file. I'd like to implement something like the <script> tag in HTML, and I've found a few links that explain how to add a new tag to HTML. I figure developers will have to connect to a js file with the language parser (it's actually more than a parser, but that's besides the point) in the head of their HTML file, like so: `<script src="my-lang.js"></script>`. Here are some of the links I've found:
https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-custom-html-elements-2
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

Here are some of my questions, assuming I want my language between <my-language> tags:

1. How do I prevent the browser's HTML parser from misinterpreting whatever is in the <my-language> tags as HTML code? All the code in my language would show up as plain text on the website from what I can see.
2. How can I implement my parser into the JS file? I'm not asking how to parse a custom language, just where to put it. The first link mentions a `createdCallback()` function that is called when a <my-language> tag is used. Assuming nobody adds a <my-language> tag with JavaScript later (which for this language that would be pointless) that callback should be called anytime the custom tag is used.
3. To parse my language, should I access the innerHTML attribute of my custom tag? I don't know if by parsing time the tag even has that attribute, or if I have to add that attribute, as I'm not familiar with how that part of it works.

Thanks for putting up with my silly questions. I like to dive into the deep end with this stuff even though I'm fairly new at this part of scripting. Basically, this is what I want the code to look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><script src="my-lang.js"></script></head>
    <my-language>
        //do some stuff in my language, like DOM editing. 
        //Just a replacement for JavaScript basically that doesn't serve much purpose.
    </my-language>
</html>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best way to go would be to use a script element with a custom language definition

Comment: So basically what handlerbars, backbone, and other libraries do with script tags to hold  templates.

Comment: Care to expound? I'm looking for the functionality of the script element, so if that's an option I'd love to hear more about it. Maybe leave an answer with a description of what you're talking about.

Comment: Similarly, and I think it's semantically quite good, as that's what script tags are for.

Comment: As the new answer says, as new script type would be the way to go. But I would use something like "text/myLanguage" because that's a valid mime type

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I like these ideas, curious though if it's feasible as a professional looking solution. Right now I'm just planning, but I'd like to eventually turn this into a real programming language for web development.

Comment: Do you have a github where I can watch progress, I would be interested in this. I wrote a little (but quite capable) lexer a while ago myself, but didn't do much with it then.

Comment: At the moment, no. I've got a bunch of other projects I'm working on right now, so this will not move along very fast. If you'd like to share what you made I'd love to see how far you got. I made a programming language called Sapphire long ago so I'm familiar with the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a new nonstandard tag in the HTML, I would recommend considering using a `<script>` tag. Although `<script>` tags are *often* for Javascript, this is not always the case. For example, one possible technique for the server to send data for the client's JS to parse is to put JSON in a tag like `<script type="application/json">{"foo":"bar"}</script>`. Scripts with types other than `type="javascript"` will not be attempted to be parsed as Javascript, but the data inside the tag can be *retrieved* with Javascript. You can do that by selecting the tag and then accessing its `textContent` property. (The `innerHTML` property is probably only appropriate when you deliberately want to retrieve HTML markup - otherwise, probably best to use `textContent`)

You can use nearly the same technique, but rather than `JSON.parse`ing the content of the `<script>` tag, send it through your parser.

For example:

```js
const tag = document.querySelector('script[type="myNewLanguage"]');
const scriptText = tag.textContent;

// use your parser to parse scriptText
scriptText.split('\n').forEach(line => {
  console.log(line);
});
```

```html
<script type="myNewLanguage">foo
bar
baz</script>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the quick reply. So the top code snippet would be a separate file? I'm trying to keep as much of the inner-workings away from the HTML file and make it easy to implement for whoever is coding in HTML. Out of curiosity, could I then use the links I referenced above to define a tag that basically boils down to what you put? Thanks

Comment: If you wanted to remove the custom language from the HTML, you would have to make a network request to access the code, which would mean a bit more delay before the code gets executed. It's a perfectly fine option, it's just a tradeoff you'd have to consider. I wouldn't recommend using custom elements as in your links because their support is too spotty - it's too new of a technology to be supported by many older browsers. It also looks like custom elements are meant to be used to contain *HTML markup*, which isn't what you're doing.

Comment: Great, thanks for the suggestion. I'll definitely be implementing this. Also I plan to use the same syntax as a server side language with built in support for basically Node.js' Express and Python's Flask. Is there a way to, when serving files dynamically, insert a `<script src="my-lang.js">` into their HTML when using Express in Node.js or Flask in Python? This way it's almost like my language is automatically supported in HTML. Don't know if this should be a separate question, but I figured I'd ask you.

Comment: I don't know Flask/Express, but I'm pretty sure non-Javascript, non-image resources can't be loaded automatically from the HTML alone (like with a `src` attribute) - pretty sure a Javascript network request is the only way it can be done. (unless you were wiling to link to a Javascript file that *contains your custom code*, eg a script that contains `window.myCustomScript = \`<lots of code in your custom language>\`;` - but that's pretty weird)